# C# How to match items from two list boxes

Tags: c#, string, winforms, listbox

I am trying to create a match the column game using two list boxes. when the user clicks on the number 100 for example in the first listbox,they then need to click on an animal in the second listbox which matches that number. Once all columns have been matched I want to display a message to the user telling them how many answers they had correct. Also I understand that using a dictionary would be a better way of doing this however I am not sure on how to correctly implement it with my listbox and randomize it

*issues I am facing

- my list Boxes are adding duplicate values

*what I need help with

- assigning a number to an animal
- matching items between two list boxes by clicking on them
- displaying a message at the end indicating how many answers were correct

Code:

```
public partial class game : Form
{
    
    public static List<string> animals = new List<string> { "cat", "dog", "bird", "frog", "snake", "duck", "tiger" };
    public static List<string> values = new List<string> { "400", "200", "300", "800", "100", "500", "600"};

    public game()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();

        //random class created
        Random random = new Random();
      
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int index = random.Next(values.Count);
          
            //adds numbers to listbox
            listBox1.Items.Add(values[index]);                                
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {         
            int index = random.Next(animals.Count);

            //adds animals to listbox          
            listBox2.Items.Add(animals[index]);
        }
    }
    
}
```

[image: as you can see my listbox is adding duplicates]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to randomly connect two different lists with the same size?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
      {
        "100",
        "dog"
      },
      {
        "200",
        "cat"
      },
      {
        "300",
        "bird"
      },
      {
        "400",
        "parrot"
      },
    };

    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      foreach(KeyValuePair < string, string > kvp in test) {
        listBox1.Items.Add(kvp.Key);
        listBox2.Items.Add(kvp.Value);
      }
    }
    
    private void listBox2_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (test[listBox1.Text] != listBox2.Text) {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
      }
      else {
        MessageBox.Show("Correct");
      }
    }
```

The added benefit here is we are using the dictionary to populate the listboxes so we dont have to manage the collection in the UI. ALso dont forget to add an event listener for **SelectedValueChanged** on your **listbox2**